Unity Netcode for Lan Multiplayer
i'm new to Unity Netcode.
i want to test some lan networking connection.
i added the Netcode package in unity and worked with some features.
heres my problem. i want to make connection between my other devices that is connected in same wifi but i dont want to the client have to enter the host ip.
i want to this work like the clients connect to same wifi and they only press host and join button and the devices connect automaticly.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yCQ26wADnDM&pp=ygUSdW5pdHkgbmV0Y29kZSB3aWZp
this is the example that i dont want to use.

thats why you would use unity relay, or make some bastardised hybrid like i did where the host registers the code and ip on a central website and clients go to the website to get host details

this might be a very stupid idea. you could setup a udp listener on each device. then to find each other, one of them would send a message to the broadcast adress of the network. the other device would recive the broadcast and therefore knows the ip of the first device. there might be some issues with firewalls and you would need to figure out the broadcast adress of the current network
